# Vertical ListView with horizontal groups

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to get a ListView to display items with the same property on the same row, so that a ListView bound to `Items` (or a grouped version thereof), defined like this:

```
class Thing {
    public Thing(int num) { Num = num; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

List<Thing> Items = new List<Thing> {
    new Thing(1), new Thing(2), new Thing(4),
    new Thing(5), new Thing(3), new Thing(4),
    new Thing(6), new Thing(4), new Thing(6),
    new Thing(3)
};
```

would look like this:

[image: Sketch of the desired ListView]

(The boxes on the same row are supposed to be the same size)

I've tried binding the ListView to a CollectionViewSource, which was bound to `Items.GroupBy(x => x.Num)`, but I couldn't get the ListView to stack the groups vertically, and use horizontal stacks inside the group.

I've also tried an approach with nested ListViews, basically like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsGrouped}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ThingGroup>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

It felt really wrong, and I still couldn't get the items to stretch to the full available width, so I'd like to find an approach with the single ListView and groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tackle 2 issues here.

Firstly you need to make sure you are receiving Items grouped by your `Num` so that it can be easy to bind. For that we can use `Linq` to create a `IGrouping` List. Like Below.

```
List<IGrouping<int, Thing>> FinalItems = Items
            .OrderBy(a => a.Num)
            .GroupBy(a => a.Num)
            .ToList();
```

Then I am Binding that to ListView

```
MainList.ItemsSource = FinalItems;
```

Now for the second part where you need to stretch the Items based on the sub items, [UWP Community Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/) has a control called `AdaptiveGridView` that stretches Items based on available `Width`

You can use this inside your Nested ListView so that Items can stretch Based on the Number of SubItems.

So your `XAML` will be something like below.

```
<ListView x:Name="MainList" Margin="0,20">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Toolkit:AdaptiveGridView ItemsSource="{Binding ''}" DesiredWidth="100">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Num}" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </Toolkit:AdaptiveGridView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

And the final Output will be

[image]

Full Repo can be found [Here](https://github.com/avknaidu/SO44783636)

Good Luck.